# Make @HostBinding and @HostListener conditional in a Directive or Component for Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I have a directive that accepts an event:

`<td calendarEvent [event]=event><td>`

Inside the directive, I have `HostBinding`s for adding classes based on the event and `HostListener`s for listening for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. For example:

```
@HostBinding('class.all-day') get eventIsAllDay() {
  if (this.event) return this.event.is_all_day;
}
```

A number of `<td>`s will have `undefined` for the `[event]` input. Is there a way for `HostBinding` and `HostListener` to be added based upon a condition? On every change detection, it has to run all the bindings and listeners for every single `<td>` tag, even those that don't have events. Perhaps the computing power needed is negligible, but every little bit helps I'm sure, especially with mobile devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to add those conditionally.

You can use a property and bind to the property instead. Change detection with properties is more efficient than with functions or getters.

```
@HostBinding('class.all-day') 
eventIsAllDay:boolean = false;

set event(val) {
  this.event.is_all_day === val;
}
```

Comment: I know this an old answer but you can use "Renderer2" to listen "on demand" to something. See my comment here for more information on that topic: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7626#issuecomment-611991619

Comment: Has this changed since Günter answered in 2016? Consider editing the answer to discuss the solution mentioned by @mhombach

Comment: @ChanceSnow no, it hasn't changed. Renderer2 is an abstraction to make DOM access compatible with server-side rendering, but it boils down to registering an event listener imerpatively (using JavaScript)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Not sure if there is a misunderstanding here, but my proposed solution was a "on demand event listener" for scenarios where the click-process should only be firing under certain conditions. Take for example a dropdown that is listening for a global click "somewhere on the page" for closing that dropdown. That click-event and checking would be executed every single time the user clicks "something" with the mouse. In that case it's way more performant to start listening for global clicks when the dropdown is opened. And Angular perfers its Renderer2-abstraction, so i recomm. it.

Comment: Angular doesn't prefer Renderer2. That was a very long time ago. Renderer2 is only required if you want to be compatible with server-side rendering (SSR). If that is not required, then the Angular team suggests not rather using Rederer2. Renderer2 is just an abstraction over direct DOM access (which would cause errors with SSR because there is no DOM).